# SQL Server Integration Service Left Join

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I've been trying translate the next ACCESS query into a SSIS data flow:

```
Insert into A.column1, A.column2..    
Select B.column1, B.column2, C.column1, C.column2    
from B left join C on B.column3 = C.column3    
Group by A.column#    
Having B.column# is null
```

Until now I have created the next data flow

**(Excel source and DB source) -> Merge Join -> Data Conversion-> Conditional Split -> DB Destination**

But when I try to insert the query in the Merge Join I am having the next message error:

**The isSorted Property must be set to True on both sources for this transformation.**

So I go to the property window but I do not see nothing like this in the list of properties.

What can I do in order to fix this problem?, or even better, do you know a best way to do this query in SSIS?

Comment: Look for the IsSorted property in the Advanced tab of your Source components (Excel and DB).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. By looking a little bit further, a I have found this example, which I consider is very useful for people like me that are new in the use of this tool. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1322/merge-multiple-data-sources-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IsSorted property is in the Input and Output Properties tab of the Source Component.   You will need to set it to true, and also specify which column the results are sorted on, by selecting that column and setting the SortKeyPosition property to 1.  If the results are sorted by more than one column, you do the same for the other columns:   The SortKeyPosition is a 1-based list of the order the columns appear in the ORDER BY clause of the SQL that generated your source component.