# Sorting Merge Join output

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis, etl, dataflowtask

I have two merge joins in data flow task. I want to set the IsSorted property for inputs of second merge join.
But it is giving error as "The IsSorted Property must be set to True on both sources of this transformation."
following is the image of this:

[image: img]

**UPDATE 1**

From the answer and the comments below, the `IsSorted` property can be found in the Data sources (Excel + OLEDB) advanced editor. But the Merge Join Transformation doesn't have this property. And i need to Merge the first Merge Join output with the Excel Source without using a Sort component.

Comment: I think you have to use "Sort" data flow task before adding input to "Merge" task.

Comment: I don't want to use Sort task in this.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but couldn't. I have input of merge join as another merge join. Make sure your `practice locations` is sorted via advance properties.

Comment: But I think Union All works as union operation in sql server. I don't want to do that. I just want to do left join operation.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat for reply. The practice location is already sorted. The main issue is we cannot set the IsSorted property for first merge join. The property is available for data sources only and not for intermediate transformations like merge join.

Comment: Right click on your data source and select `Show Advanced Editor...`.  The `IsSorted` property is in the `Input and Output Properties` Tab

Comment: @AmolR : I tried to replicate your issue. Kindly double check. Merge-join when taking input as another merge-join and source, it only needs `is sorted` for source. In my case, it perfectly worked. Just make sure your second source has 'is sorted' correctly put. ssis won't understand even if your source is already sorted. you'll have to set it manually.

Comment: @Prabhat: I tried adding sort transformation for second source, but still it is throwing that error.

Comment: I suggest you import the excel file into a staging table and do the join in the database. Doing it this way is kinda complicated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Integration Service Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656932/sql-server-integration-service-left-join)

Comment: @TabAlleman i don't think this is a duplicate, he is asking to sort the merge join output.

Answer (score 2):

## Update 2 (Workaround)

After the merge join add a script component in which you will add one output column (will be used as second join key). In the script just assign the original key value to this column.

Then in the script input and output properties, set the Output `IsSorted` property to `True`

*Example:*

[image]

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
    Output0Buffer.outEmployeeName = Row.EmployeeName
    Output0Buffer.outEmployeeNumber = Row.EmployeeNumber
    Output0Buffer.outLoginName = Row.LogineName


End Sub
```

## Update 1

If your are looking to generate Sorted output from the Merge Join transformation, then i recommend you to follow this link:

- [Merge Join component sorted outputs [SSIS]](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/31/merge-join-component-sorted-outputs-ssis.aspx)

## Initial Answer

The `IsSorted` property can be edited from the Advanced Editor,

Just right-Click on the `OLEDB Source` (or `Excel Source` if needed) , go to the `Input and Output Properties`, click on the Output and you will find the `IsSorted` property in the properties Tab

[image]

Then you souhld set the `SortKeyPosition` for the columns

[image]

Comment: I did that but it only works for first merge join. It doesn't work for second one.

Comment: If the next merge join is with the excel source then you must set the `IsSorted` property on the `Excel Source`

Comment: @AmolR what are the inputs of the second merge join?

Comment: First Merge Join output and Practice Locations output.

Comment: @Did you set the `IsSorted` property for all inputs?

Comment: That is the issue. The IsSorted property is only available for Excel source and not first Merge Join. So I cannot do it.

Comment: @AmolR after searching for this issue, i think the only way is to add a sort component after the first merge join.

Comment: @AmolR https://krazycoder.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/merging-two-or-more-tables-in-ssis/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But in that they used Sort transformation for sorting. I don't want to use that because of performance issues. I simply want to set IsSorted property and do the work.

Comment: @AmolR i provided a new helpful link in the answer (UPDATE 1), check it out i think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Be careful with IsSorted = true on an excel workbook. If data starts coming unsorted you will get duplicates in your load. I learned this lesson tha hard way.

Comment: @KeithL i agree with that

Comment: Thanks Hadi, Will try Update2 and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hadi, I did not get where to set IsSorted property in Script Componenet. Can you elaborate more on this.

Comment: @AmolR click on the Output and you have to set SynchronousInput property to none, then the `isSorted` property will appear. but then you should write the whole script (if you need more help writing the script then give me a feedback)

Comment: @AmolR i added an example, take a look